# Can I open a file in a branch different from the active?

Tags: git

Say I have a branch "work" and a branch "ideas" in my git repository.

I usually work on my marvelous_file.cpp in "work" branch, but sometimes I would like to open
at the same time the marvelous_file.cpp that is in my "ideas" branch.

I don't want to see what the differences between the two files, but rather take snippets of codes from the "ideas" branch and copy and past them in the file in the "work" branch.

Is this possible? If not, can I checkout the file in "ideas" into "work", but with a different name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `git show` to do that:

```
git show ideas:marvelous_file.cpp
```

This will show it right in the Terminal. If you want that as a file, just pipe it into a file, e.g.:

```
git show ideas:marvelous_file.cpp > ideas.cpp
```

Comment: thanks it worked! I love git, but sometimes I feel that certain tasks should be made more immediate :) git checkout-as command would be nice (maybe I can add an alias to do this?)

Answer (score 0):

If you commit your changes locally first, these steps will work just fine:

```
git checkout ideas -- path/to/your/file.txt
```

will grab the file that you want and replace the one that you have in your working folder. You can do this for an entire directory or the whole work tree:

```
git checkout ideas -- .
```

will grab the entire work tree

```
git checkou ideas -- dir/with/cool/stuff
```

will grab all the contents of the directory.

Now you can

```
git reset -p
```

to systematically throw away the changes you don't want. This may be easier to grab snippets that you want if they are already placed into the files you're going to be working on.